How to display custom bone properties in Pose Mode at all times?
I've recently made IK-FK switch drivers for my rig experiment in Blender 4.1.0 using this tutorial, but I have to select the gear bone above the character's head in Pose Mode to access the IK-FK switches.

When I select this bone, I can see the custom bone properties.

When the bone is not selected, they are not shown. This is a minor annoyance I'd like to get rid of.
Is there a way to display these switch properties in Pose Mode when ANY bone is selected, so I don't have to select the gear bone every time?
Here is my .blend file if that helps: 
